# Getting ajaxterm to work on Debian Lenny

Tags: ssh, debian, ajax

I've been knocking my head out for a while on this one and have read many tutorials, but I just can't get this to work. Ajaxterm, is a webbased SSH client; once installed `apt-get install ajaxterm` and then enabling it with `/etc/init.d/ajaxterm start` I should be able to access the SSH terminal with http://mywebsite:8022/

But doing so only gives me a "Page not found", any suggestions?

My actual VPS is: http://173.244.205.160
My sources:
https://secure.kitserve.org.uk/content/setting-ajaxterm-Ubuntu-and-Debian-powerpc

http://wiki.kartbuilding.net/index.php/ajaxterm

Comment: There's something about the concept of ajaxterm that scares me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Ajaxterm only listens on localhost:8022 so it won't be listening on your VPS's IP address:8022. You have to install and configure Apache if you want to access it on an address other than localhost:8022. Fortunately the [second link you provide](http://wiki.kartbuilding.net/index.php/Ajaxterm) contains instructions for doing just that.

EDIT:

I don't know Debian - hopefully Ubuntu will be close enough.

- Create a vhost file e.g. `ajaxterm` in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and add the configuration from the Ajaxterm wiki.
- Enable the vhost with `a2ensite ajaxterm`

Comment: thanks for clearing that up. On the page linked, it says "Put the following in an Apache vhost file" where can I locate this vhost file?

Comment: @KevinDuke: See my edit.

Comment: thanks lian -- I really appreciate this, some hold up though, http://pastebin.com/B2DFQLyB it's saying I have an Invalid command 'SSLEngine' in apache2? however I haven't touched that file. Here is my apache2.conf  http://pastebin.com/cMq12nZr

Comment: @KevinDuke: You may need to put `NameVirtualHost *:443` in your apache2.conf file

Comment: hmm I added that in a random location and I get the same error. sorry I'm so stupid, any suggestions?